# Search for old emails that are NOT starred (Gmail)

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

Gmail has a search bar where you can filter emails. For example, to see emails from December 2019:

```
before:2020/01/01 after:2019/11/30
```

Or to see emails before the start of 2020 which are starred:

```
before:2020/01/01 is:starred
```

But how do you ask for "Emails before the start of 2020 and which are NOT starred? I've tried combinations like `before:2020/01/01 NOT is:starred` or `{before:2020/01/01} - {before:2020/01/01 is:starred}` but nothing works.

[This Google help article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) covers more options, but I wasn't able to work out a way to select a negation (like the C/C++ `!` operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing for longer, the following command works:

```
before:2020/01/01 -is:starred
```

There must not be any space between `-` and `is:starred`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

`-label:starred after:2019/01/01 before:2019/12/31` shows me non-starred e-mails, received in 2019.

[image]